# Cocoa app with tabs like Xcode.app Terminal.app

Tags: cocoa

I've been reading the documentation but couldn't find any build-in component that implements something like Terminal.app or Xcode.app tabs.

Is there any component that will give me such functionality? are they as just customized NSTabViews? if so are there any examples around?

I am looking for the most standard or classic way of doing this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I know of no ways to implement a tab view such as in Safari, Xcode, Terminal, or Finder. However, there are some good alternatives to this on https://www.cocoacontrols.com. I do not know of anyone who as designed a custom control to look like the Safari/Xcode tabs yet. I would recommend using the google chrome style tabs: https://github.com/rsms/chromium-tabs
After the Chromium Tabs, I would suggest using: https://github.com/monyschuk/LITabControl.

Other options include: https://github.com/shinyfrog/SFTabView, https://github.com/onekiloparsec/KPCTabsControl, and https://github.com/dorianj/PSMTabBarControl/. I hope you are able to find one that works well for your application!

Comment: At the time of asking the question there was not simple way of doing this. (not build it in Cocoa) but since macOS10.12 it is possible. See NSWindow Automatic Window Tabbing https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#10_12Window%20Tabbing